# Hp proliant Dl380p gen 8 power issue

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, electrical-power

Hi my hp proliant dl380p gen 8 sometimes lunches into the hp loading screen then shuts off other times it doesn't get to loading screen and just try's to start up you can hear it and see it send power thru the system but shuts off the health light is blinking red

`https://quickshare.samsungcloud.com/qiotBJjBQ5Ka`

Comment: Welcome and thank you for posting. Getting good answers requires a clear and useful question which is [well written](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681) , [on-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) and contains all the relevant details to provide you with a good solution. Please don't link to third party sites for details but include them in your question proper. - Please improve your question to address those points or run the risk of leaving your problem unresolved and/or having your question closed.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your RAID setup is done and correct. You have 0 logical drive and an error as the array is not configured. If you had a OS prior, it mean your RAID setup was flushed or new drive was inserted that wasnt part of a RAID before hand. If so restore a backup and recreate your array.

[image]

I ask as I seen that error; which mean your OS can't load.

[image]

For your red light, I suspect it's your second PSU that is not plugged in that cause it;

[image]

Comment: Ok thanks I'll take look at it all

Comment: I did all this still same

Comment: @ToggleLite well, in what config you did your RAID ? RAID 1/5/6 ? what OS you installed after on it ? It can't boot well otherwise

Comment: so i bought the serve i have reconfigured the raid to raid 1 and haven't been able to put a os on it yet as it just shuts down when trying to load one up